# Architecture routing from a message between 2 responders

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I read myself a bit about azure service bus. There many examples how I can set it up, create a queue and get information from the queue. 
Now I have a question. When I have a second responder (for example an azure function / With different functionality) I must create a new queue? Or how is routing from the message between these two responders.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your message to be received and processed by more than one receivers, you should look into Service Bus Topics.

Service Bus Topics are meant for one to many mapping, where a message sent to a Topic can be received from different Subscriptions.